# ElasticSearch 5, document time to live, create and update

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch 5 and I need my document, older than X days/weeks or a date, to be automatically deleted. I am not sure **_ttl** is available in 5 but from what I read Elastic do not recommend it any way.

I will update my documents, it is only the one non update for a define period that I need deleting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do that for all docs which are older than a date X, then it's definitely better to create one index per period (let say per day) then after X days, simply drop the index.
It's a way more efficient than doing delete doc operations.

If it's with a given query, docs that are older than X days and match XYZ, then add yourself a timestamp within your doc and run a delete by query call every day.

Comment: thanks for that.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

That works for me